# pattern matching in list intersection in Python 3

Tags: python, regex, intersection

I'm a beginner in Python and my goal is to write a pre-receive hook residing on a git  server.

The hook is supposed to check the format of commit messages and reject a push if any of the messages fail the format check.

I think I got this bit working for a simple commit-pattern comparison as below:

```
commit_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
patterns = ['test1','test2']

matched = set(commit_list).intersection(patterns) # find matches

for match in matched:
    commit_list[:] = (commit for commit in commit_list if commit != match) # remove matches from commit_list

commit_list_length = len(commit_list)

if commit_list_length == 0: # all commits matched so the list is empty
    print('all commit messages match the format')
else:
    print('%s of the commit messages don\'t match the format' % commit_list_length)
    print(commit_list)
```

How do I modify this snippet to include regexp e.g: `re.match(pattern,commit)` ?

So that it still works when the second line is changed to e.g:

```
patterns = ['test[0-9]{1,5}','test: ']
```

Comment: First of all, you could refactor much of your existing code with `not_matched = set(commit_list).difference(patterns)` if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, right?

Comment: @timgeb well, that wouldn't be exactly equivalent, since it would remove duplicate items that didn't match, and it would remove the order. But definitely something like `patterns = set(patterns); commit_list = [x for x in commit_list if x not in patterns]` would be and would be practically as efficient. Alouth for this purpose I believe `.difference` would still work

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes, I made a few assumptions . Adam, are order and retainment of duplicates important?

Comment: For a success each commit message must match any of the patterns not all.
Needless to say the solution needs to be scalable and work for any number of commit messages and any number of patterns >= 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change code to include `re.match()`, you can try this.

```
import re
commit_list = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']
patterns = ['test1','test2']
regx=re.compile(r'{}'.format("|".join(patterns)))
commit_unmatched=[commit for commit in commit_list if not regx.match(commit)]
print(commit_unmatched)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found a working solution although, almost certainly, not the shortest or most efficient one:

```
commit_list = ['test1', 'test234', 'testA', 'test:a', 'test: a']
patterns = ['test[0-9]{1,5}','test: ']

cloned_list = list(commit_list) # copy list of commits

for item in commit_list:
    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.match(pattern,item):
            cloned_list.remove(item) # work on the copy and discard matched
        elif not re.match(pattern,item):
            continue # exhaust all possibilities

cloned_list_length = len(cloned_list)

if cloned_list_length == 0: # all commits matched so the list is empty
    print('all commit messages match the format')
else:
    print('%s of the commit messages don\'t match the criteria' % cloned_list_length)
    print(cloned_list) # only print unmatched
```

still willing to try better suggestions!